# Modify part in Altium by exploding (or other method)?

Tags: components, altium

There is a design in which I must remove silkscreen from every part, and I would like to do this without having to create footprints for every part that needs to be modified since I have many footprints and orientations.

Is there a way to modify a single part?

I know I can explode parts by going to tools->convert->explode component into free primitives. But if I rejoin the compoents the part does not come back. Is there a way to rejoin the exploded components back in to the part after modifying it?

Comment: Do you want any silkscreen on the board at all?  If not, just order the board without silkscreen.  If you do want some silkscreen, you may be able to omit the official skickscreen layer, and use another layer for the silkscreen you want.  (I'ts been some time since I used Altium - don't recall what could be done with extra layers...)

Comment: I do want silkscreen on the board, just not on the part (and I actually want it on the part, but not in a certain area of the part), I guess I could post process it with a gerber editor, but then if you need to re export the board, you have to redo all the edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the properties for a part, you can "unlock primitives". In older versions you would uncheck a box next to the "primitives locked" property. In recent versions (19 and 20, at least) you click a padlock symbol next to the word "primitives". Then you can modify the part as you like.

[image]

Re-lock the primitives afterwards to avoid accidentally messing up the footprint.